# How do I access data of one jsx file in the other jsx file in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

the component shown is an editable table. i need to send data of this component and the parent component to a seperate component on a submit button click in the parent form. Im new to this. Can someone help me? i have to access the datasource on the button click. is there some kind of expression to call the data from child directly in the parent?
     i have to access the datasource on the button click. is there some kind of expression to call the data from child directly in the parent?

```
export default class EditableTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.columns = [
      {
        title: 'Backup Of',
        dataIndex: 'backupOf',
        render: (select, record) =>
          this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                      <Select name='backupOf' defaultValue='Select'>
                        <option value="1">Files Or Folder</option>
                        <option value="2">SQL DB</option>
                       </Select>
          ) : null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Server IP',
        dataIndex: 'serverIp',
        editable: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'Server Type',
        dataIndex: 'serverType',
        render: (select, record) =>
        this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                    <Select defaultValue='Select' name='servertype' >
                      <option value="1"> Production</option>
                      <option value="2"> Dev</option>
                    </Select>
        ) : null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Frequency',
        dataIndex: 'frequency',
        render: (select, record) =>
        this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                    <Select defaultValue='Select' name='freq'>
                      <option value="1"> One time</option>
                      <option value="2"> Daily</option>
                      </Select>
        ) : null,
      },
      {
        title: 'Backup Drive',
        dataIndex: 'backupDrive',
        render: (select, record) =>
        this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
                    <Select defaultValue='Select' name='backupdrive'>
                      <option value="1"> LTO2</option>
                      <option value="2"> LTO3</option>
                    </Select>
        ) : null,
      },

      {
        title: 'operation',
        dataIndex: 'operation',
        render: (text, record) =>
          this.state.dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}>
              <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          ) : null,
      },
    ];

    this.state = {
      dataSource: [
        {
          key: '0',

        }

      ],
      count: 1,
    };
  }

  handleDelete = key => {
    const dataSource = [...this.state.dataSource];
    this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource.filter(item => item.key !== key) });
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
    console.log('datasource................',this.state)
    const newData = {
      key: count,

    };
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
      count: count + 1,
    });
  };

  handleSave = row => {
    const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      ...item,
      ...row,
    });
    this.setState({ dataSource: newData });
  };

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    const components = {
      body: {
        row: EditableFormRow,
        cell: EditableCell,
      },
    };
    const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }
      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave,
        }),
      };
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          components={components}
          rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
          bordered
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={columns}
          style={{overflowX:"scroll"}}
        />
        <Button onClick={this.handleAdd} style={{marginTop: 16 }}>
          Add a row
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know more about the parent component? The solution depends on how you are currently handling data. Based on what I'm seeing you have two options.

1. You should move the data to the parent component where it holds both components that share data being handled. To have a more centralized data management.
2. Or you could put the function in the parent component and bind it so data can be passed there to be thrown to another child component.

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
import EditableTable from "./backupRequestTable";
export default class Backup extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props); render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>       <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} id="backupRequest">
<EditableTable/><button type='submit' className="btn btn-dark mr-4" style={{ width:80 }}>Submit</button></div>
       </form>
            </React.Fragment>   
        );
    }
}

Comment: this is the essentials of the parent. sorry about the formatting

Comment: Here's an example of placing the function and data on the parent component and pass the function and data to the child components.https://codepen.io/fluffyflores/pen/EqWymg